# My label.text is nil with Reusable library in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, tableview

I'm trying to show the label with content "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA". I'm using Reusable library. Although I connected IBOutlet right way, the label and imageView of cell did not show content.

This is my cell class

```
import UIKit
import Reusable
import SDWebImage

protocol ChooseMemberTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func addUserToGroup(forUser user: User)
}

class ChooseMemberTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, Reusable {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    func setupCell(data: User) {
        userNameLabel?.text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA"
//        userNameLabel?.text = "\(data.userName)"
//        let url = URL(string: data.image)
//        userImageView.sd_setImage(with: url ?? "", completed: nil)
    }
}
```

This is my ViewController, which i register cell

```
//
//  MembersViewController.swift
//  Message
//
//  Created by Minh Tâm on 1/9/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Minh Tâm. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import Reusable
import Then

private enum Constants {
    static let numberOfSection = 1
    static let heightForRows: CGFloat = 60
}

final class ChooseMembersViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var searchMembers: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet private weak var listContacts: UITableView!

    var searchUser = [User]()
    private let database = Firestore.firestore()
    var users = [User]()
    private var currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    private var roomRepository = RoomRepository()
    private var userRepository = UserRepository()

    var groupName: String?
    private var selectUserArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        userRepository.fetchUser()
        configListTableView()
        fetchUser()

    }

    func configListTableView() {
        listContacts.do {
            $0.register(cellType: ChooseMemberTableViewCell.self)
            $0.delegate = self
            $0.dataSource = self
        }
    }

    public func fetchUser() {
        database.collection("users").getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                    for document in snapshot.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                        if uid != self.currentUser?.uid {
                            let newUser = User.map(uid: uid, dictionary: data)
                            self.users.append(newUser)
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.searchUser = self.users

                self.listContacts.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func handleBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false)
    }

    @IBAction func handleDone(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let currentUser = currentUser, let groupName = groupName else { return }
        selectUserArray.append(currentUser.uid)
        let time = NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))
        roomRepository.updateFirebase(groupName: groupName, time: time, selectUserArray: selectUserArray)
    }

}

extension ChooseMembersViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            searchUser = users
        } else {
            searchUser = users.filter { $0.userName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
        }
        listContacts.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ChooseMembersViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return Constants.numberOfSection
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchUser.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = listContacts.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: ChooseMemberTableViewCell.self).then {
            let user = searchUser[indexPath.row]
            $0.setupCell(data: user)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return Constants.heightForRows
    }
}

extension ChooseMembersViewController: ChooseMemberTableViewCellDelegate {
    func addUserToGroup(forUser user: User) {
        let selectedUserUid = user.uid
        selectUserArray.append(selectedUserUid)
    }
}
```

Cell does not show information of label and imageView

Comment: I do that when i register cell. If i put `$0.delegate = self` in cellForRowAt , the Xcode notifies `Value of type 'ChooseMemberTableViewCell' has no member 'delegate'`

Comment: okay, i did add, but the label till not show T.T

Answer (score 0):

1. `ChooseMemberTableViewCell` is correct, but I'd recommend use `userNameLabel.text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA"` (not optional for `userNameLabel`)
2. If you use cell from Storyboard into your `tableView` - **no need** to register this one, the UIStoryboard already auto-register its cells. I mean you should remove this line: `listContacts.register(cellType: ChooseMemberTableViewCell.self)`
3. You **should** add identifier `ChooseMemberTableViewCell` for cell in Storyboard
   [image]
4. This **should** work for `cellForRowAt`:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: ChooseMemberTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
    cell.setupCell(data: user)
        .then {
        let user = searchUser[indexPath.row]
        $0.setupCell(data: user)
    }
    return cell
}`

I guess that's all. I've done it and I see label with text in `tableView`